# jQuery translate value adding by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

```
wHeight = $(window).height();
$('.test').css({"-moz-transform":"translate(0," +wHeight+ ")" });
```

This is my code , but I am getting an error ?
How to add value by jQuery

Comment: usually .css is used with a selector 
$('selector').css();

Comment: The semicolon in JavaScript is used to separate statements / line terminator it tells javascript engine that this line is finished and after from `;` another line start,

Comment: Get rid of the `;` in the first line. Readup the examples in [.css() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: @RahulDesai probably you are asking for chain selector, but after `height()` function the selector will be written off.. and although he is assigning window height in  `wHeight` variable

Comment: @Girish- Is it wrong question?  why I got -5 ? :(  any answer ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh probably you want to add css on any element then you should use right selector, you have used `test` selector that is not any html element or any other `id, class` etc

Comment: Well what error are you getting with the current code? `$('test')` selector will search for an element `<test>` which probably doesn't exist. I think you need `$('#test')`. The downvotes are probably because you show a lack of minimal understanding. It looks like you are just doing random stuff and it would be better if you took a look at the jQuery docs and follow some examples.

Comment: I know that, we are not very beginner in jQuery , I was showing my exact issue only @Girish :)

Comment: I know that, we are not very beginner in jQuery , I was showing my exact issue only @Dark Ashelin :) ,  There is no issue in console but not taking inline style when  i use by jQuery

Comment: @ShibinRagh code fine, now what error show up in console??

Comment: //wHeight = $(window).height()
$('body').css({"-moz-transform":"translate(0," +wHeight+ ")" }); //  You can just run in your firebugg - that is better show

Comment: @ShibinRagh The fact that you don't seem to know how to correctly write a selector, nor correctly attach a function to a selector (as shown in your sample code pre-edit) leads us to believe that you lack minimal knowledge. Do you still get an error now?

Comment: wHeight = $(window).height()                          $('body').css({"-moz-transform":"translate(0," +wHeight+ ")" });     -  You can just run in your firebugg - that is better show, No error for me :)  @Dark Ashelin

Comment: you missed `px` in css try this code `wHeight = $(window).height(); $('body').css({"-moz-transform":"translate(0," +wHeight+ "px)" });`

Comment: @Girish  Great great This was my problem , really thanks , but my question is still in -5 :(

Comment: @ShibinRagh No, we will not "run the code in firebug ourselves". It will not work because we are not testing on the same page as you. If you want us to see the problem, create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and recreate the issue there.

Comment: @DarkAshelin  ohh yes , Finlay I got the solution , I missed "px" , but I am sad my Question is -4 :(

Comment: @ShibinRagh that is because your question was written badly. Please see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `px` in css `translate(0, npx)` is correct, jQUery `css({})` function won't add default `px` when css property has multiple param

this would be correct, if single param

```
$("<selector>").css({'height': wHeight})
```

but `translate()` properly takes multiple params so you will need to add `unit` with value

```
$('.test').css({"-moz-transform":"translate(0," +wHeight+ "px)" });
```